# Docker compose .env default with fallback

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to save a `docker-compose.yaml` file inside a git repo.
I would like to have some default `.env` variables, but I would like to have also something like `.env.local` which could override `.env`, but I don't want to commit `.env.local` so it should be gitignored.

Is there any way to tell `docker-compose.yaml` "use .env.local if exists, otherwise .env"?

The idea is to allow someone to clone the repository, use their own `.env.local` if they want, without having git changes to commit or use default `.env` values if they don't want to customize it.

Comment: Compose itself will only automatically use a file named .env nothing else. Even then, you need to name the variables you want to use from that. Otherwise, you have to use an env_file key.  I don't think there is a fully automated way to handle this, unless you are willing to add your defaults inside the compose file.

Comment: How about using something like `.env.example` as the commited file and use the `.env` as the personal env file?

Comment: :( what a pitty this functionallity is not supported, anyway I like @dEBAM solution, thanks!!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you are using the values from the env file by name, like below. You can use [posix parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) like shown to get default value behavior. Compose will use the value for that variable from `.env` file or if it's set in your shell, otherwise it will default to *default-value*.

```yaml
services:
  myapp:
    environment:
      SOME_VALUE: ${SOME_VALUE:-default-value}
```

If you are intending to use it under the key `env_file` you can use the knowledge from the above example do to some tricks.

```yaml
services:
  myapp:
    env_file: ${ENV_FILE:-.env.example}
```

Now it will by default use `.env.example`. Unless you happen to place a `.env` file at the root of your project (from where you invoke compose) and overwrite the `ENV_FILE` variable in there. Or export it in your shell. Note that the .env file must include `ENV_FILE=.env` in order to expand to .env in env_file:

```bash
ENV_FILE=.env
OTHER_STUFF=foo
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241214/discussion-between-miquel-and-the-fool).